# Layout hides behind sticky bottom app bar

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, appbar

I have added a bottombar in windows winrt application like this.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar RequestedTheme="Dark" Background="#FFF3A716" IsSticky="True" IsOpen="True" >
        ...            
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

But after adding the issticky property my content starts hiding behind app bar.

Is there any way that app bar doesn't open above my layout.

It should open below my layout. So that my layout doesn't shows correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just added margin = 120 for bottom of my layout and solved the issue.